# Java- apache http client- usage examples showing use of cookies and extracting response from HTTPResponse object

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I am working with apache http client (v4) in a java web app, and I am stuck in the following cases, for which I require simple usage examples--

(1) How to use Cookies with Apache HTTP client, different options available for usage of cookies

(2) Extracting charset, mimetype, response headers (as KeyValuePair) and budy (as byte[]) when the response is available in HTTPResponse object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)AS for cookies,see that exapmle:

httpcomponents-client-4.1.3\examples\org\apache\http\examples\client\ClientCustomContext.java

main code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            // Create a local instance of cookie store
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

            // Create local HTTP context
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/");

            System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

            // Pass local context as a parameter
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

2)You can get all you need from response and:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
entity.getContent()
```

Just read the examples in:
httpcomponents-client-4.1.3\examples\org\apache\http\examples\client
of httpcomponents-client-4.1.3-bin.zip which is downloaded from its [website](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).